# PHP - URL variables captured and passed to next page

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

Right now, I have a page that loads with a bunch of information from PayPal after a payment. I need to capture 5 of those pieces of information (`payer_id`, `amount`, `payment_type`, `payment_status`, and `custom`) and store them in order to have the following page load event be able to interact with that data. (This site is done using CodeIgniter.)

Assuming I use a `$_GET`, but I'm getting a little lost with this. Anyone able to help?

Example URL: `http://example.com/page3.php?payer_id=8675309&amount=300&payment_type=instant&payment_status=complete&custom=182&...`

FOR CLARITY: I want to extract the variables I'm after from the URL, assign them somewhere, and then I'll call them from my function to store them in the DB. I can't do this on page load, so I have to do it afterwards.

Comment: You're trying to store data received from the PayPal IPN. Why not use a database, like anyone else would do?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the data for the url in codeigniter, or how to store it?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but the URL already exists on page load, and I can't figure out how to initiate the function to store it until I'm done with whatever work I have to do on the following page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is what you need?

```
$payer_id = $this->input->get('payer_id');
```

Simply change parameter name (payer_id, amount, payment_type, payment_status, and custom) to retrieve its value

You would need to enable following in `congif.php`

```
$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
```

**HINT**:    http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html